# Extracting price from an html string and convert to xml

Tags: php, html, xml

This is a sample of the string of data that i need to extract the price of.

"Price Rs 475 000 - CHEVROLET AVEO LS // SEP 11 6,000 kms - Red.. full options.. MANUAL 5 door // hatchback Contact me on 786 8394"

I have many such strings after crawling a particular website and there can be any number or words in the string.

I have tried to separate each word by a space and store it in the array $arr. I have declared another array for storing identifiers of price $arrPrice.
if the word price or rs is found,then the data (eg 475 000) is stored in the variable $price. However as i have exploded it with space, it is not taking into consideration the 000 . I am getting only 475 in the xml tag.

The efficient way of doing it may be with regex,but i am not good at it. Grateful if someone could help me.

Find Below my codes till now,

Thanks!

```
    <?php


    foreach($html->find('div.field-content') as $e) {//find the h3 element that contains class field content


    $arrPrice = array("rs", "price","rs."); // an array of identifiers to retrieve price

    $str = $e->innertext;// crawled data from a website
    $str = strtolower($str); //converting string to lower case
    $arr = explode(" ", $str);//creating an array of the string by seperating it from the spaces

    if (strlen($str) > 0) {
        $price='';

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++) {

            //finding price 
            for ($j = 0; $j < sizeof($arrPrice); $j++) {
                if ($arr[$i]==$arrPrice[$j]) {
                    $price = $arr[$i+1];
                    //echo 'Price='.$arr[$i+1];

                }
            }   

        }
        $xml.="<Cars>";
        $xml.="<Price>".$price."</Price>";
        $xml.="</Cars>";
    } 

    else {
        echo "String is blank";
    }


}

$file = fopen('data.xml','w');
if(!$file) {
    die('Error cannot create XML file');
}
fwrite($file,$xml);
fclose($file);
```

?>

Comment: Is the price always going to be in the same position?

Comment: no it is not standard, it can be in any position.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $arr[$i] == $arrPrice[$j] ) {
  $price = $arr[$i+1];
  if ( isset( $arr[$i+2] ) && is_numeric( $arr[$i+2] ) ) {
    $price .= $arr[$i+2];
  }
}
```

And so on..

Comment: Thanx Salman. As i mentionned, i have several strings that have been crawled,but i am not getting each price in its respective xml tag.

Comment: Maybe you have to write different logic to parse different strings.

Comment: i was thinking of using preg_match_all() but as i said i am not good in regex :(